# Communication between an asynchronous model process and a controller on iOS

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC programming and I understand that if I want my controller to talk to my model I just have to create a var in my controller and use it.

What happens when I have a process going on in my model and I want to let my controller know it is done, how can I use my completion handler in that type of communication?

Comment: Posting what you have done (the code you have, the code you tried etc.) would be helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use completion handler, as you created model as global variable

```
var yourModel = YourModel()
```

call method in your model with completion handler.

method in your model like

```
// Method 
func saveData(completion: @escaping(_ status: String) -> Void) {
   // Do your business logic here ......
   //...
   // end of business logic and call completion
   completion("Successfully saved")
}
```

in your ViewController call the model method

```
yourModel.save(completion: {(status) in 
 // user status here....
 print(status) // Successfully saved
})
```